# DB Query replaces %s inside LIKE operator

Tags: 6, database

I have one query like :

`db_query("SELECT * FROM {foo} WHERE bar LIKE '%supply%' LIMIT %d,%d", 0, 10)`

Now if I use `db_query` API it will replace `%s` with the argument supplied and resulting query will be like

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar LIKE '0upply%' LIMIT 0, 0`

Any ideas to overcome this ? I dont want to use `mysql_query()`

I am using temporarily `_db_query()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to escape `%` signs with another `%` sign in a Drupal db query:

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM {foo} WHERE bar LIKE '%%supply%%' LIMIT %d,%d", 0, 10);
```

If you wanted to use a placeholder it would be like so:

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM {foo} WHERE bar LIKE '%%%s%%' LIMIT %d,%d", 'supply', 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

I answer belatedly but it might be useful to another.

Simply set the LIKE condition as a string placeholder and passes its value as an argument to the function `deb_query()`:

```
db_query("SELECT * FROM {foo} WHERE bar LIKE '%s' LIMIT %d, %d", '%supply%', 0, 10);
```