# Using LIKE in search query

Tags: 7, search, database

I would like to search for words that **contains** the keyword when a user executes a search. I have tried to hook into `hook_query_alter()`:

```
function MYMODULE_query_alter(&$query) {
  // Check if this is a search query   
  if (!$query->hasTag('search_node')) {
    return;
  }

  $conditions = &$query->conditions();
  $conditions = &$conditions[1]['field']->conditions();
  // Change the condition to '%<keyword>%'
  // and add LIKE as operator
  $conditions[0]['value'] = "%" . $conditions[0]['value'] . "%";
  $conditions[0]['operator'] = 'LIKE';
}
```

I can alter the search query, but I'm not getting any results.

The modified query that gets executed looks like this:

```
SELECT FROM {search_index} i
  INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = i.sid
  INNER JOIN {search_total} t ON i.word = t.word
  WHERE (n.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0)
    AND ((i.word LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_1 ESCAPE '\\'))
    AND (i.type = :db_condition_placeholder_2) 
  GROUP BY i.type, i.sid
  HAVING  (COUNT(*) >= :matches)
```

And the placeholders in the `SelectQuery` object are set to:

```
[:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1
[:db_condition_placeholder_1] => %liv%
[:db_condition_placeholder_2] => node
```

I can verify that the tables `search_index` and `search_total` both contain a couple of words that contain `liv`, so this should return some results.

I have also tried [Fuzzy Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/fuzzysearch) module, but I don't know how I can connect the provided search to the ordinary search form.

Notice that I have tried `db_like()`, but without any success.

I don't understand why it should be so hard to change the default search to search through the index using a `LIKE` rather than `=` condition?

Something like this should work if I only knew how to implement it:

```
$keyword = $_GET['s'];
$status = 1;
$types = array('article', 'contact');

db_query("SELECT node.nid FROM {node} n
  INNER JOIN {search_index} si 
    ON si.sid = n.nid 
    AND si.word LIKE :keyword
  INNER JOIN {search_dataset} sd ON sd.sid = n.nid
  WHERE n.status = :status AND n.type IN (:types)
  GROUP BY n.nid", array(
    ':keyword' => '%' . db_like($keyword) . '%',
    ':status' => $status,
    ':types' => $types
  )
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DB Query replaces %s inside LIKE operator](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40721/db-query-replaces-s-inside-like-operator)

Comment: @Mołot - I don't think this is duplicate. It's mostly related to the particular search query.

Comment: If you tested that's not about % substitution, then OK, at least you have one possible reason covered and can move to others. Have you tried to cast your query to string and see how it actually looks like?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the solution described in the other question and it did not work. And I have dumped the `$query` argument and after I have modified it using the code above it looks fine and updated, but it still don't returns any results. If I search for a whole word that is inside the index for instance `living` then I get a result as expected. It feels like the modification to the search query does not get applied.

Comment: You're overwriting the conditions with something in a variable called `$where`, which doesn't exist in that local scope. What's that line supposed to do? I'd wager It ain't doing it

Comment: whats that 'field' ??

Answer (score 1):

you connect the the fuzzy search via [search api pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page) module (or views).

when using views you can place the views search block in your desired region.

Manual instructions: (from fuzzy search)

- From the main Search API configuration page, create a server using the Fuzzy Search service class.
- Create an Index using the server you just created.
- Click the Workflow Tab.
- Enable "Complete entity view".
- Enable the following processors: Both Fuzzy search processors, Ignore case, HTML filter, and Tokenizer.
- Move the Fuzzy Search excerpt processor to the bottom of the list, and the Fuzzy Search search settings processor just above it.
- The default settings should be fine.
- You will need the Search API Pages module or Views to provide a place to search your site.
- Go to the main Search API page,
- Click Search Pages, add a search page, and configure with the index you created above, multiple terms for query type, and view mode as themed as search results.
- For Views, make a new view using the default fuzzyseach index, add a page display and configure as desired.
- Run cron to index your content. Visit the path for your search page.

Comment: and how can i execute a fuzzysearch programatically?

Comment: I would also like to use the same for as for the normal search can this be done? The thing is that I need this for an existing site that uses the core search from Drupal 7. And I want to avoid updating the actual theme and so on.

Comment: search api can be configured to overtake the system (normal) search, plus you can embed your search api views everywhere programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You get no results with your altered query because of what [`SearchQuery::parseSearchExpression()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.extender.inc/function/SearchQuery%3A%3AparseSearchExpression/7) does to it. Specifically, around line 300:

```
// Single ANDed term.
else {
  ...
  $this->conditions->condition('d.data', "% $key %", 'LIKE');
  ...
}
```

Notice the spaces in the condition.

To get any results you'd have to remove those spaces from the query which isn't a simple task. I believe something like this would be required:

```
function my_module_query_alter($query) {
  if ($query->hasTag('search_node')) {
    $conditions = &$query->conditions();
    $conditions = &$conditions[1]['field']->conditions();
    $conditions[0]['value'] = '%' . $conditions[0]['value'] . '%';
    $conditions[0]['operator'] = 'LIKE';
  }

  if ($query instanceof PagerDefault) {
    PagerDefaultHelper::alter($query);
  }
}

class PagerDefaultHelper extends PagerDefault {
  public static function alter(PagerDefault &$query) {
    $search_query = &$query->query;
    SearchQueryHelper::alter($search_query);
  }
}

class SearchQueryHelper extends SearchQuery {
  public static function alter(SearchQuery &$query) {
    $conditions = &$query->conditions->conditions();
    $conditions[0]['value'] = str_replace(' ', '', $conditions[0]['value']);
  }
}
```

However, this will only work when searching for a single word. You would have to build on this approach for searches that use multiple words, OR'd words or excluded words.

Comment: This seems like something that might work. I will be testing this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I add **db_like($prefix)** using [db_like](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_like/7) may be it worked!

```
(i.word LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_1 ESCAPE '\\')

Convert into:

 condition('i.word', db_like($prefix) . '%', 'LIKE')
```

I am not expert in customization but may be it helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to solve this problem, but I ended up using [`hook_node_update_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update_index/7) to support searching for parts of words:

```
function hook_node_update_index($node)
{
   $result = '';

   // how long should each part be?
   $options = array(3, 4, 5);

   // only look at the body and title
   $content = $node->body['und'][0]['value'] . ' ' . $node->title;
   $content = strip_tags($content);
   $content = drupal_strtolower($content);

   $words = explode(' ', $content);

   $parts = array();

   // split words into parts
   foreach ($words as $word) {
     // if the length is less than the size we would like to split at
     // then there's no need to continue
     $length = drupal_strlen($word);

     foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($length < $option) {
           $result .= ' ' . $word;
           break;
        }
        for ($i=0; $i < ($length - $option + 1); $i++) {
           $parts[] = drupal_substr($word, $i, $option);
        }     
     }
   }

   // append all created parts for the words
   if(count($parts)) {
      $result .= ' ' . implode(' ', $parts);
   }

   return $result;
}
```

From the documentation:

> **function hook_node_update_index**
>
> Act on a node being indexed for searching.
>
> This hook is invoked during search indexing, after node_load(), and
>   after the result of node_view() is added as $node->rendered to the
>   node object.

I add this as an answer, since it might help someone in the future. I still looking for a better solution that uses a `LIKE` conditions for each keyword.

Comment: This solution may work on a small site, but if you have more than a handful of nodes it will make the search really slow. It may also return incorrect results by returning a node with "restaurant" when someone searches for "rest" or "ant" even if the post has nothing to do with rest or ant.

Comment: It should not make the actual search slow but the indexing that takes place when ever cron runs. Yes I'm aware that this might return incorrect results, but since the search always should perform a wildcard/fuzzy search this would be as expected.

Comment: It will make indexing slow as well, but having a larger index makes the search slower (time to perform a search increases with the number of items in the index - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347552/what-is-the-big-o-for-sql-select for example).